# Dynamically resize/space text to fit div

Tags: css, asp.net-3.5, font-size, letter-spacing

I have a `div` with a fixed width, but the text inside (someones name) will vary. Is there a way of dynamically resizing/letter-spacing the text to fit perfectly in the `div`?

However, I **cannot** use javascript as this script will be used in a HTML-PDF converter, which does not read javascript

`text-align:justify` won't work as if the text is too long for the div, it won't resize it. I find `text-align:justify` only works for paragraphs etc.

The name cannot go onto two lines

Comment: Does the name have to all fit on one line?

Comment: @tjm Yes, thats right, the name has to fit all on one line

Comment: There's `text-align: justify` but I believe that works when there's more than one line. Other than that, probably no way with simply CSS. You can center them, that might be better than leaving them aligned left.

Comment: Since you're using ASP to generate it, maybe you can count the number of characters and put each one in a span with the appropriate width/font-size in an inline style?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use either:

```
 Graphics graphics = this.CreateGraphics();
 SizeF textSize = graphics.MeasureString("How long am I?", this.Font);
```

or

```
 Size textSize = TextRenderer.MeasureText("How long am I?", font);
```

TextRenderer is less accurate, but Graphics requires you to use a windows form - in your case you could have a form with a single textbox into which you place the text to be measured and then read it back, but TextRenderer is simpler.

Using the above you could write a function that adjusted the font-size until the desired length was reached.

It would then be a case of setting the style on the text sent to the browser to reflect this font-size.

Comment: Everythings possible. I could loop through each letter putting it in a div floated left with a width and font-size set. But this could be buggy.

Comment: How are you going to loop without javascript?

Comment: ASP.NET function. Check my tags :)

Comment: OK - well you can likely get closer to filling the div, but not "perfectly" unless all of your clients are completely identical. Different machines will have different fonts/browsers/monitors/user settings, all of which could have an impact on the relative sizes of the text and the div.

Comment: This is not an issue as this will only be viewed by one client browser (the servers). This is then converted to a PDF, and given to the user. So once its spot on, it won't change

Comment: OK - in that case answer above